# nested dictionary from text file, return None for missing value

Tags: python, csv, file, dictionary

I have a text file details.txt which contains data like

```
Name,Job,Country,Color,Animal
Abby,Manager,Berlin,Green,Dog
Amy, Pianist, Korea,Red,Cat
Jhones,Designer,Australia,Black,Dog
Nayla,Student,USA,,Cat
Oly,Singer,Canada,Blue,,
```

I am trying to make nested dictionary, Names are the keys, and rest are corresponding values. If any information/value missing in file then value should be None.

```
The result I want
'Abby': {'Job': 'Manager', 'Country’: ‘Berlin', 'Color': 'Green', 'Animal':'Dog'}
'Nayla': {'Job': 'Student', 'Country’: ‘USA', 'Color': None, 'Animal':'Cat'}
```

since I solved the index error, now my Qs is how to get None in '' missing values of the dictionary

```
def nested_dict(x):
    
    d = {}
    
    with open(x,'r') as file1:
        lines = file1.readlines()
            
        for w in lines:
               words = w.rstrip().split(',')
                             
               if words[0] not in d:
                  d[words[0]] = {'Job': words[1], 'Country': words[2] 'Color': words[3], 'Animal':words[4]}        

    return d    
nested_dict('details.txt')
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated! Still learning so there could be a lot errors in my code.

Comment: As an aside, `lines = file1.readlines()` is not necessary, you can iterate directly over `for line in file1: ...`

Comment: so I am over doing it? Apart from that may I as which one causing other errors? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: You need to provide more information. The code you've given doesn't produce an `IndexError`, with the file you provided

Comment: I solved it! partially!  it was throwing error because of the last line. so I did ```[:-1]``` in lines :) now I know why it was throwing error, because last line was one string.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a Comma Separeted Value (CSV) file. Usually they have a `.csv` extension.
They are a very common file format.
What I usually do is use the [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) library to work with CSV files.

So, if you have the possibility to install new libraries in your Python environment, I would suggest to install Pandas and then do this:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("details.txt")
df.set_index("Name", inplace=True)
```

Then, if you want to get info about a specific person, you can do:

```py
df.loc["Abby", :]
```

You can also do many other things with the Pandas library, such as do calculations (e.g. how many people in your dataset have a "Dog" as `Animal`?), write new CSV files...

If you do not want to install Pandas, you can still read your file using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, which is part of the standard library, so it is already included in your Python installation. But I personally recommend Pandas, it is very powerful!

Comment: :) is there any usual and boring way, it will help me to find out my mistakes.

Comment: @Anna.balouch , why reinventing the wheel, when awesome programmers created libraries such as Pandas or csv to handle your situation?
The main difficulty (and the cause of your error) is the presence of empty strings (i.e. None values) in some cells of the CSV file.
The libraries I mentioned already manage that situation, and you will know what cells are empty in your original file!

Comment: :) well said. Agree with you. But sometimes the teachers want us to learn from very basics and gradually introduce us to import files, library from other incredible sources.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `csv` module and a `csv.DictReader`. Then you can do something like:

```
import csv
with open("example.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    result = {d.pop("Name"):d for d in reader}
```

But in your example, to start from the second line, just do something like:

```
for w in lines[1:]:
    ...
```

Comment: any other way without importing csv? I mean very normal and boring way, will help me to understand my error. :)

Comment: @Anna.balouch your way should work, if you handle the header correctly. Please provide a [mcve]. Also, if you are getting that error, post the full error message including the stack trace. And you really should at least print out the offending line.

Comment: I should thank you! I solved it! partially! it was throwing error because of the last line. so I did [:-1] in lines :) now I know why it was throwing error, because last line was one string. (a github link), now I need to look for ways to get None for missing values :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not want to use any external library (such as Pandas or csv), try this solution:

```py
file_name = "details.txt"

with open(file_name, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines = [line.rstrip() for line in lines]

columns = lines[0].split(",")


def parse_sub_dict(columns, raw_values):
    values = raw_values.split(",")
    
    sub_dict = {}
    for column, value in zip(columns, values):
        if value == "":
            value = None
        
        sub_dict[column] =  value
    
    return sub_dict

list_dicts = [parse_sub_dict(columns, line) for line in lines[1:]]
nested_dict = {sub_dict.pop("Name"): sub_dict for sub_dict in list_dicts}
```

As others have pointed out in the comment, there is an "error" in the file you posted: there is one excess "," in the last line.
My solution solves the problem in `parse_sub_dict` function, where `zip(columns,values)` returns an iterator the length of `columns`, which is your first line.

Comment: You are welcome! If you like the solution, please give it an Up vote!

Comment: oh yes I did up voted, but I think I need to have some more points/privileges to do that :/ new to rules